# Can React native Alert wait for user response?

Tags: react-native

Can React native Alert wait for user's response (just like pausing the app) instead of just popup and proceed the following logic?

I think js alert will just pause the application.

Answer (score 22):

Here's what you can do with `Alert`:

You can set cancelable with false, so the user can't close the alert without pressing a button

You can set a callback with each button.

Also you can wrap the Alert with Promise so you can use async

```
const AsyncAlert = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Alert.alert(
            'Title',
            'Message',
            [
                {text: 'YES', onPress: () => resolve('YES') },
                {text: 'NO', onPress: () => resolve('NO') }
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
        )
    })
}    

// Then to use the method
const userResponse = await AsyncAlert()
// ...the rest of your code
```

Comment: I set cancelable as false, but if I add a console log below the Alert, even if I haven't clicked on "YES" or "No", then console message still show up, which means the app is still running the following code instead of pausing on Alert dialog to wait for user response.

Comment: What do you mean by pausing?

Comment: Taking my above case as example, the console log message under Alert code should not be shown before user click "YES" or "No".

Comment: Alert isn't async, so you need to put your code inside those callbacks, after console.log('YES pressed') and the other one

Comment: Yep, I understand this part. I'm updating an existing code package which will make things easier if we can make Alert async and await for the user response. Do you have any idea if we can achieve this?

Comment: Thank you! I tried this method, but it doesn't work on the app I'm working on. Not sure if it's the function itself doesn't work, or my app has a different way for handling state. But thanks for your effort, I give a vote.

Answer (score 5):

I have taken the @Tareq El-Masri code and edited it. changing it to a async function will work.

```js
const AsyncAlert = (title, msg) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  Alert.alert(
    title,
    msg,
    [
      {
        text: 'ok',
        onPress: () => {
          resolve('YES');
        },
      },
    ],
    { cancelable: false },
  );
});

await AsyncAlert();
```

Answer (score 3):

While the other answers are pretty much correct, they still require the reader to manipulate the functions to use in their own code (eg. to change buttons, etc). Here is a nice exportable version that allows you to pass in a function to create any button setup you need:

```js
import { Alert as NativeAlert } from 'react-native';

const defaultButtons = (resolve, reject) => [
  {
    text: 'OK',
    onPress: () => {
      resolve();
    },
  },
];

const AsyncAlert = (title, msg, getButtons = defaultButtons) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    NativeAlert.alert(title, msg, getButtons(resolve, reject), { cancelable: false });
  });

export default AsyncAlert;
```

Use like this:

`await AsyncAlert('Some Title', 'Some message.')`

If you want custom buttons, just pass a function in as the third argument (which gets resolve and reject, should you need either.