# Use a React Native Alert to confirm/block Back button navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to prompt the user for confirmation before using the stack navigator's back button by doing something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825503/can-react-native-alert-wait-for-user-response), but the result my result seems to be different.

```js
const defaultGetStateForAction = SignedIn.router.getStateForAction;

const asyncGetUserConfirmation = () => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Alert.alert(
   "Discard changes?",
   "Your post will be lost if you confirm.",
   [
    {
     text: "No, continue editing",
     onPress: () => {
      resolve(false);
     }
    },
    {
     text: "Yes, discard changes",
     style: "cancel",
     onPress: () => {
      store.dispatch(setPost({}));
      resolve(true);
     }
    }
   ],
   { cancelable: false }
  );
 });
};


SignedIn.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  if (
    state &&
    action.type === NavigationActions.BACK &&
    Object.keys(store.getState().post).length
  ) {
    asyncGetUserConfirmation().then(continueAction => {
      console.log(continueAction);
      return continueAction ? defaultGetStateForAction(action, state) : null;
    });
  } else {
    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
  }
};
```

When the user touches the back button, the `if` in `SignedIn.router.getStateForAction` works properly (no questions asked if post is empty, alert pops otherwise).

I expected that the user would be redirected back if `continueAction` were true (at the end of the snippet), however after the user interacts with the alert, the correct result is displayed on console but regardless of `continueAction` being true or false, the user is not navigated back.

Everything else is working as intended, so what would make `return continueAction ? defaultGetStateForAction(action, state) : null;` be "ignored", without even throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

**To show the confirmation before using the stack navigator's back button you can override onPress of stack navigator.**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Alert } from "react-native";
import { HeaderBackButton } from "react-navigation";

export default class Detail extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const handleClearPress = navigation.getParam("handleBackPress", () => {});
    return {
      title: "Details!",
      headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton onPress={handleClearPress} />
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // set handler method with setParams
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      handleBackPress: this._handleBackPress.bind(this)
    });
  }

  _handleBackPress() {
    // Works on both iOS and Android
    Alert.alert(
      "Discard changes?",
      "Your post will be lost if you confirm.",
      [
        {
          text: "No, continue editing",
          onPress: () => console.log("No, continue editing")
        },
        {
          text: "Yes, discard changes",
          onPress: () => console.log("Yes, discard changes"),
          style: "cancel"
        }
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Detail Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this can solve back action with left swipe gesture..

Comment: @highjump you can check out my answer