# react native remove item from flatlist with confirmation in alert

Tags: react-native, alert, react-native-flatlist

i'm trying to remove an item from flatlist but before remove it there is an alert to ask "are you sure to remove it".

but i couldn't sure how to do it.

this is alert

```
<AwesomeAlert
        show={showAlert}
        title="UYARI!"
        message="Are you sure to remove it?"
        closeOnTouchOutside={false}
        closeOnHardwareBackPress={false}
        showCancelButton={true}
        showConfirmButton={true}
        cancelText="Hayır"
        confirmText="Evet"
        confirmButtonColor="#DD5555"
        onCancelPressed={() => {
          setShowAlert(false);
        }}
        onConfirmPressed={() => {
          //what should i do here ? 
          setShowAlert(false);
        }}
      />
```

this is flatlist render item

```
const barcodeList = barcodeArray => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.ListItemContainer}>
        <Text>-{barcodeArray.item}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => removeItem(barcodeArray.item)}> 
                                //this removeItem func is remove it without confirmation
          <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>X</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the item passed to removeItem function you can filter out the value and then set state.

eg

```
let filter_elements = item.filter(
item => item.id!= barcodeArray.item.id
);
setState(filter_elements)
```

Comment: i can remove item but i need to remove it when user press the alert's ok button

Comment: are you using Alert.alert from react-native?, there based on option you can trigger the removeFunction

Comment: i'm using awesomeAlert package. it is up there how i use it

Comment: just move your removeItem function above to AwesomeAlert onConfirmPressed, you can use a state where you can store the id of the element which you pressed and then use that state while running function removeItem(stateId)

Comment: thx, i thought maybe i can do that without using state. but using state is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Actually your alert component should return a promise.

Something like that:

```
const removeItem = id => {
    alert("Are you sure?").then(if(value === "Yes") => {
        // do some stuff here

        
    })
}
```

You can write a async alert.

[Can React native Alert wait for user response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825503/can-react-native-alert-wait-for-user-response)